# Webpage downloader

Tags: java, html

I wanted to download a webpage. I confirmed that this code works. But I'm not sure whether I'm doing it neatly. Would you review my (full) code?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.URL;

public class GetHTML {
    private InputStream in;
    private FileOutputStream out;
    private String articleName;

    public void setArticleName(String articleName) {
        this.articleName = articleName;
    }

    public void download(URL url) throws IOException {
        in = url.openStream();
        out = new FileOutputStream(articleName + ".html");
        byte[] arr = new byte[1024];
        while(true) {
            int count = in.read(arr);
            if(count == -1) { break; }
            out.write(arr, 0, count);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String site1 = "http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/";
        String site2 = "69";
        String site3 = "is-this-implementation-of-shamos-hoey-algorithm-ok";
        URL url = new URL(site1 + site2 + "/" + site3);
        GetHTML getHTML = new GetHTML();

        getHTML.setArticleName("[" + site2 + "]" + site3);
        getHTML.download(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Can you use automatic resource management? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943542/using-keyword-in-java 2. Pass the article name directly to the constructor. 3. Take the url from command line. 4. Keep it simple - e.g. every method could have been static.

Comment: I think I will not be able to take the url directly from command line because actually I have a bunch of url's. :( This is just a small program, and I hope to grow this program into a giant which will be able to handle thousands of url's automatically! :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. From Clean Code, page 25:

   > Classes and objects should have noun or noun phrase names like `Customer`, `WikiPage`,
   >   `Account`, and `AddressParser`. [...] A class name should not be a verb.

   I'd simply name it `ArticleDownloader`, for example.
2. ```
   private InputStream in;
   private FileOutputStream out;
   ```

   These could inside the download method:

   ```
   public void download(URL url) throws IOException {
       final InputStream in = url.openStream();
       final OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(articleName + ".html");
   ```

   Reference: *Effective Java, 2nd edition, Item 45: Minimize the scope of local variables*
3. The `FileOutputStream out` could be just `OutputStream` type. (*Effective Java, 2nd edition, Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces*)
4. Commons IO has a method which does the copying: [`IOUtils.copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29). (*Effective Java, 2nd edition, Item 47: Know and use the libraries*)
5. I'd remove the `setArticleName` method and the `articleName` field (since there is no other method which uses this field) and pass it directly to the `download` method:

   ```
   public void download(URL url, final String articleName) throws IOException {...}
   ```
6. I'd move the `main` method to a separate class. (For example, `DownloaderMain`.) It's usually a good idea to separate a class from its clients.
7. Close the streams in a `finally` block. (*Effective Java, 2nd edition, Item 7: Avoid finalizers*)